# anchor point in CCMenu or CCLayer in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, anchor, cocos2d-x

I understand concept of anchor point for a sprite.
(It tells which point of the texture will be at the sprite's position. e.g., if anchorPoint=(1,0), bottom right corner of the texture will be at the sprite's position)

I'm looking at CCMenu source code of cocos2d-x, and it set's anchorPoint, m_bIsRelativeAnchorPoint, and Position in its init method..

Can someone explain what those variable means here when CCMenu apparently has no texture associated with it?

Answer (score 0):

You understand not right. Anchor point does not relatieve to the sprite's texture. It is relatieve only to the node's contentSize. Just in case of CCSprite it's content size is automatically set to the size of your picture (even not texture, because texture of the picture with size, for example, 129x129, will have size 256x256)

Answer (score 0):

Anchor points and texture coordinates are different.

Here is one good post on Cocos2D anchor point: [Click Here](http://www.qcmat.com/understanding-anchorpoint-in-cocos2d/)

Rotation, scaling and positioning of sprite is done with respect to this anchor point. For example:

```
sprite.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5,0.5);
```

Say sprite width = w, sprite height = h

In this case, when you access position property of sprite, it gives position where the pixel 
point ( w x 0.5, h x 0.5 ) is located in parent node. Rotation also done in same point.